# What is the role of "It" in this two sentences?

Tags: parts-of-speech

1.It rains quite often here in the summer.

2.It is hard to believe that he is dead.

Some clarification will help me to identify the parts of speech of "it" in both sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Mm, good question.  "It" here is referring to the general state of existence, a sort of placeholder for large unwieldy concepts like the tides or life and the universe, or a sort of restructuring of the sentence for a different emphasis.

Without the placeholders I might write those sentences like this:

> The moisture in the air precipitates and rains down quite often here in the summer.

> The fact of his death is hard to believe.

but it's a tough one to answer without using "it".